# Constructor set the account to the first trasaction address

Tags: solidity, accounts

I,m trying to block the call to the getOrigin function to accounts that are not equal to the account that is set in setOrigin function.

Now the first account that call to setOrigin is the unique that can call and see all the information of all the new values.

How can I change the constructor account value in each call that I do to the contract??

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "browser/DateTime.sol";

contract Travel {

address private owner;

modifier isOwner
{
    require (owner == msg.sender);
    _;
}

struct TravelStruct 
{
    //Origin
    address clientAddress;
    string originAirportName;
    uint32 originTime; //In timestamp
    uint16 originBagWeight;
    //Tape
    uint32 tapeArrivedTime; //In timestamp
    //Plane
    string flyCode;
    uint32 takeOffTime; //In timestamp
    //Destiny
    string destinationAirportName;
    uint32 destinyTime; //In timestamp
    uint16 destinyBagWeight;
}

mapping(uint => TravelStruct) travels;
uint public travelsRegistryCount;

constructor()
{
    owner = msg.sender;
    travelsRegistryCount = 1;
}

//  ORIGIN PART
function setOrigin (string _originAirportName, uint32 _originTime, uint16 _originBagWeight) public
{
    travels[travelsRegistryCount].clientAddress = owner;
    travels[travelsRegistryCount].originAirportName = _originAirportName;
    travels[travelsRegistryCount].originTime = _originTime;
    travels[travelsRegistryCount].originBagWeight = _originBagWeight;
    travelsRegistryCount++;
}  

function getOrigin (uint _id) isOwner public constant returns (address, string, uint32, uint16)
{
    return (travels[_id].clientAddress, travels[_id].originAirportName ,travels[_id].originTime ,travels[_id].originBagWeight);
}
}
```

The problem that I have is that the constructor parameters are setted in the fist time that I call to a function. But my idea is to renew the constructor parametes each time that the call is made from another account.

Is that possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per solidity documentation:

> When a contract is created, its constructor (a function declared with
>   the constructor keyword) is executed once.

Constructor runs only once at the time of deployment. Afterwards you cannot trigger it anyhow. That is a functionality of `constructor`

You can design the required logic using the regular functions of contract.

Comment: Thx for the answer A.K.

Comment: If it answers your question correctly, please mark it as right answer